# My app crashing immediately when compiled

Tags: ios, xcode

My app crashing immediately when compiled, below is the error I'm receiving.

> 2013-07-02 18:39:20.272 RecipeV6[41361:c07] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key search.' *** First throw
>   call stack: (0x1c97012 0x10d4e7e 0x1d1ffb1 0xb80e41 0xb025f8 0xb020e7
>   0xb2cb58 0x236019 0x10e8663 0x1c9245a 0x234b1c 0xf97e7 0xf9dc8 0xf9ff8
>   0xfa232 0xfa4da 0x1118e5 0x1119cb 0x111c76 0x111d71 0x11289b 0x1129b9
>   0x112a45 0x21820b 0x692dd 0x10e86b0 0x2293fc0 0x228833c 0x2293eaf
>   0x1082bd 0x50b56 0x4f66f 0x4f589 0x4e7e4 0x4e61e 0x4f3d9 0x522d2
>   0xfc99c 0x49574 0x4976f 0x49905 0x52917 0x1696c 0x1794b 0x28cb5
>   0x29beb 0x1b698 0x1bf2df9 0x1bf2ad0 0x1c0cbf5 0x1c0c962 0x1c3dbb6
>   0x1c3cf44 0x1c3ce1b 0x1717a 0x18ffc 0x2b2d 0x2a55 0x1)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Can anyone help me debug this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: paste your code here and we might be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all UI elements (right mouse click) and IBOutlets connected in your XCode. Some reference problems will be assigned with a Warning icon (see Figure). Clean it, solve the references, misses classes or objects and rebuild the code!

[image: XCode References]

Comment: This could also happen if you had properties set on views in interface builder, then changed the view class to something that doesn't implement those properties